# Is there any way to represent a DFA (Deterministic finite automata) into an adjacency List?

Tags: java, c#, graph, state, dfa

So, I have a very big DFA and it's filled with PHI's, so I want to convert it to an adjacency list to save a lot of memory and use it to check the if input is accepted or return the state that the input stands on.

And I searched a lot about but found nothing...

I know the code for weight graphs, but in DFA machine there are multiple weights.

Another thing, when we move on a DFA transition table we use this code

`state = DFA_TransitionTable[state][weight];`

And I need an alternative for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to represent a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) with an adjacency list in Java. Instead of having an array for the transition function, you represent it as a map of "symbols" to "states", so that given a state and a symbol, you get the next state with `state.transitionFunction.get(symbol)`.

```
class DFA {
    Set<State> states;
    State initialState;
    Set<State> acceptStates;
}

class State {
    Map<Symbol, State> transitionFunction;
}

class Symbol {}
```

This assumes that you want to have a `Symbol` class of your own - you can of course use Character or String for the traditional use case where the DFA is applied to strings.

Comment: Thank you very much , and i think i should see if there is a transition before adding to the map